# Test to release for under 4s

Tags: france, england, quarantine, covid-19

I am planning on using the test to release scheme for a trip to England at the beginning of August.
I am a British national living in France, double jabbed with Pfizer. I will be travelling with my 3 year old child, also a British national living in France unvaccinated.
**Does my 3 year old also have to opt in for the test to release scheme or is he exempt from quarantine requirements?**
He is exempt from testing upon entry into England because he is under 11. I cannot find any information on whether he is also exempt from quarantine. I cannot find a test to release provider that tests on under 4s. This suggests to me that he is either: exempt from quarantine altogether or he has no option but to do the full 10 day quarantine.
Thanks for any responses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>If France stays on the amber list and unless the UK government changes its plan (which is very much possible), you and your child will be exempted from quarantine in August. You will still be subject to the pre-departure and day-2 tests.</s> You are not eligible for the new quarantine-free scheme since you are not UK residents and the vaccine was not administered by NHS.

> - from 19 July, arrivals who have been fully vaccinated with an NHS administered vaccine in the UK (plus 14 days), or are on a formally approved UK vaccine clinical trial, returning to England from amber list countries will no longer need to quarantine – passengers will need to provide proof of their vaccination status to carriers in advance of travel
> - pre-departure testing and day 2 testing measures to remain
> - children under the age of 18 to be exempt from quarantine on returning to England from amber countries
>
> https://www.gov.uk/government/news/quarantine-free-travel-to-resume-on-19-july-for-fully-vaccinated-passengers-returning-from-amber-list-countries

---

Children under 4s are not exempt from the quarantine and must take an approved test-to-release test to be eligible for the scheme.

> **Testing and quarantine rules for children**
>
> Children aged 4 and under do not need to take the day 2 or day 8 test.
>
> **Children of all ages** need to quarantine at home or in the place they’re staying for 10 full days (the day of arrival in England is day 0).
>
> https://www.gov.uk/guidance/how-to-quarantine-when-you-arrive-in-england#testing-and-quarantine-rules-for-children

> You will have to pay the private test provider for your test. You will need to book an individual test for each person opting into Test to Release, including **children of all ages.**
>
> https://www.gov.uk/guidance/coronavirus-covid-19-test-to-release-for-international-travel

There are test centres and take-at-home test providers that may test on under 4 years old, you might need to call them to clarify.

Comment: Sadly, -1 from me.  The OP has made it clear that sie and hir son are French residents, and HMG has [already clarified](https://www.gov.uk/government/news/quarantine-free-travel-to-resume-on-19-july-for-fully-vaccinated-passengers-returning-from-amber-list-countries) that this change is only for UK residents: "*The government is taking a phased approach to amending requirements and is already exploring plans to remove quarantine for vaccinated non-UK residents arriving from amber countries later this summer where it is safe to do so"* (published 8/7/21 and discussing the 19/7 changes).

Comment: @MadHatter You are correct, I have amended the answer. Thank you.

Comment: -1 converted to upvote - thanks!  Hopefully at some point HMG will gets its finger out and recognise there's no clinical difference between an MHRA-approved vaccine administered in the UK, and one administered elsewhere.